# IBM BPM DatetimePicker

Tags: business-process-management, ibm-bpm, brazos

in BP3 Brazos toolkit, when I use `'date time picker'` to input date and time, what type of variable should be bound?

I tried the binding date and `datetimepickerselection` type. both did not work, throwing an error.

Answer (score 6):

The BP3 Brazos UI DateTimePicker should be bound to a `date (system date)` object.

The error might be caused by additional bindings under the configuration tab.

For more information on what data-type object to bind, please refer to the online [documentation](https://brazos-docs.bp-3cloud.com/Coach%20Views.html?artifact=Date%20Time%20Picker).